# NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:oracle.oracledb

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, python-oracledb

When I Try to connect oracle server with SQLAlchemy. I'm getting this error.

NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:oracle.oracledb

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

DIALECT = 'oracle'
SQL_DRIVER = 'oracledb'
USERNAME = 'username' #enter your username
PASSWORD = 'password' #enter your password
HOST = 'host url' #enter the oracle db host url
PORT = 1533 # enter the oracle port number
SERVICE = 'service name' # enter the oracle db service name
ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH = DIALECT + '+' + SQL_DRIVER + '://' + USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD +'@' + HOST + ':' + str(PORT) + '/?service_name=' + SERVICE

engine = create_engine(ENGINE_PATH_WIN_AUTH)


#test query
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM global_name', engine)
```

any different method to connect?

Comment: Maybe [this page](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-python-oracledb-1-0-with-sqlalchemy-pandas-django-and-flask-5d84e910cb19) can help you

Comment: SQLAlchemy 2.0 is required to use python-oracledb -- at least without the directions given on the page by gsalem.

Answer (score 9):

For completeness (since the answer is already in comments): with SQLAlchemy 1.4 add this to your top level script file:

```
import sys
import oracledb
oracledb.version = "8.3.0"
sys.modules["cx_Oracle"] = oracledb
```

and then proceed as if you were using cx_Oracle.  The `create_engine()` should begin with `oracle:` like:

```
# SQLAlchemy 1.4 with python-oracledb or cx_Oracle
engine = create_engine('oracle://...
```

The `sys.modules` etc snippet isn't needed for SQLAlchemy 2.0. With this version `create_engine()` should begin with `oracle+oracledb:` like:

```
import oracledb

# SQLAlchemy 2.0 with python-oracledb
engine = create_engine('oracle+oracledb://...
```

These posts are good references:

- [Using python-oracledb 1.0 with SQLAlchemy, Pandas, Django and Flask](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-python-oracledb-1-0-with-sqlalchemy-pandas-django-and-flask-5d84e910cb19)
- [Using SQLAlchemy 2.0 (development) with python-oracledb for Oracle Database](https://medium.com/oracledevs/using-the-development-branch-of-sqlalchemy-2-0-with-python-oracledb-d6e89090899c)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I tried above method.
now I'm getting ```DatabaseError: (oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError) ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed```